# TornadoFX addClass does not add CSS

Tags: css, user-interface, kotlin, tornadofx

TLDR; When trying to change the background color of a `listview` using inline CSS with `style { ... }` it works but `addClass` using a copy-pasted CSS does nothing.

The following code (using inline CSS) works:

```
listview(monsterController.monsters) {
    vgrow = Priority.ALWAYS

    cellFormat {
    // addClass(StatBlockStyles.monsterListCell)
    style { 
        backgroundColor += Color.color(253.0 / 255.0, 241.0 / 255.0, 220.0 / 255.0) 
    }
    graphic = label(it.name)
}
```

But if I comment the `style { ... }` and uncomment the `addClass(...)` it seems to have no effect.

The CSS class is a literaly copy-paste of the inline CSS:

```
import javafx.scene.paint.Color
import tornadofx.*

class StatBlockStyles: Stylesheet() {

    companion object {
        val monsterListCell by cssclass()
    }

    init {
        monsterListCell {
            backgroundColor += Color.color(253.0 / 255.0, 241.0 / 255.0, 220.0 / 255.0)
        }
    }
}
```

Why does this happen and what should I do to be able to actually separate the styling from the rest of the code?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your init section of the view/fragment containing your listview:

```
init {
   importStylesheet(StatBlockStyles::class)
}
```

Note: You only need to use the import function once. The styling will remain for the rest of the program, even in other windows/views/fragments.